# Seeing Code Coverage for 2GP Managed Package Version

Tags: code-coverage, 2gp

I'm developing a 2nd-Generation Managed Package and working on releasing a new version. Our package depends on one "core" package which is under the same namespace.

Note: we develop the "core" package in a separate line of development, so it is installed in the scratch org using `sfdx install package` when developing. We have multiple packages using this methodology and it works well.

When I create a brand-new scratch org with the metadata for the new package, I run unit tests and get 94% code coverage. I even used the methodology laid out in [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/363001/how-to-check-apex-code-coverage-for-package-extension) to ensure that the base package installed in the scratch org doesn't affect coverage - still at 94% per the script.

I have a GitHub Action that run tests using a fresh scratch org on every push. They sit at total coverage of 94%. When the release process (automated through GitHub Actions as well) runs, it uses this command to create a package version:

```
sfdx package version create --package "$PACKAGE_NAME" --wait 120 -v devhub --installation-key-bypass -c --definition-file config/project-scratch-def.json
```

Where `$PACKAGE_NAME` is pulled directly from sfdx-project.json. This exact script works in other packages.

When I promote the package out of Beta with the following command (again, automated on GitHub Actions):

```
sfdx force:package:version:promote -v devhub -p package-id -n
```

I get the following error:

```
The code coverage required to promote this version has not been met.  Please add additional test coverage and ensure the code coverage check passes during version creation.
```

Is there a way to see what the Package version is seeing? I'd like to know what it thinks the coverage is or where I'm lacking.

**Edit:** Here is a command that can give a list of coverage for a certain package version:

```
sf package version report --package "version_id" --verbose
```

In my case, this showed that we were missing a good amount of coverage on two classes. Writing tests to more thoroughly cover those classes worked and got a release out the door.

Comment: Is it possible to deploy/install the package that's failing into a brand new scratch org *without* the other package? If you can, that would suggest that running code coverage like this should show you where the deficiencies are.

Comment: The failing package extends Apex in the core package, so it wouldn't deploy. I did find a command that gave me more info on what classes were missing test coverage. I'll edit the post with it. Interestingly, it gave me numbers different than the scratch org did. I'm writing more unit tests against the low-coverage code to see if that helps.